# Best practices for prepopulated tables via OrmLite in Servicestack

Tags: orm, ormlite-servicestack

I'm generating tables via OrmLite and I was wondering about best practices for prepopulating tables. Example tables - countries, states, cities, etc.

**I can think of a few ways to pre-populate tables:**

1. List item
2. Seed DB
3. API (when possible)
4. Static file
5. In code
6. Separate project

However, in some cases the data could get large as in the example of cities around the world so in code is not viable.

I could also consider generating tables that need to be pre-populated directly via another project where I can fetch data from a source and get it into the DB.

However, I was wondering about the scenario when you do generate it via an ORM (especially in production). How would you approach the problem?

This must be a common problem across all ORM's.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it's only **code** tables like countries, states, etc, they're small enough to still have them as part of the project, normally I'd create a separate static class called `SeedData` with all the data in POCO's

### 1. Maintaining Code Tables in Host Project

```
public static class SeedData
{
    public static List<Country> Countries
    {
        get { return new[] { new Country(...), ... }; }
    }
}
```

Then in your AppHost populate add a flag on whether to re-create them on startup, e.g:

```
public void Configure(Container container)
{
    var appSettings = new AppSettings(); //Read from Web.config <appSettings/>
    if (appSettings.Get("RecreateTables", false))
    {
        using (var db = container.Resolve<IDbConnectionFactory>().Open())
        {
            db.DropAndCreateTable<Country>();
            db.InsertAll(SeedData.Countries);
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

#### Change AppSetting to recreate tables

This will then let you re-create the tables and re-populate the data when you change the `RecreateTables` appSetting to `True`, e.g:

```
<appSettings>
  <add key="RecreateTables" value="True" />
</appSettings>
```

As the default behavior of ASP.NET will automatically restart the AppDomain, just saving a change to `Web.config` is enough to restart your ASP.NET application the next time any page gets refreshed.

### 2. Add to Test Project in adhoc Explicit Test

If the Data gets too big to fit in the working project I would first move it to a separate test project inside an `[Explicit]` text fixture (so it's never automatically run), that you can easily run manuallu, e.g:

```
[Explicit]
[TestFixture]
public class AdminTasks
{
    [Test]
    public void Recreate_and_populate_tables()
    {
        var dbFactory = new OrmLiteConnectionFactory(...);
        using (var db = dbFactory.Open())
        {
            db.DropAndCreateTable<Country>();
            db.InsertAll(SeedData.Countries);
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

### 3. Save data in external static text Files

Finally if the data is even too big to fit in C# classes, I would then save it out to a static file in the test that you can easily re-hydrate into POCO's that you can populate with OrmLite, e.g:

```
[Test]
public void Recreate_and_populate_tables()
{
    var dbFactory = new OrmLiteConnectionFactory(...);
    using (var db = dbFactory.Open())
    {
        db.DropAndCreateTable<Country>();
        var countries = File.ReadAllText("~/countries.txt".MapAbsolutePath())
            .FromJson<List<Country>>();
        db.InsertAll(countries);
        ...
    }
}
```